# Change the color of TextView after passing through them

Tags: java, android, textview

I need to do something similar. I have 5 TextView that change color when I go after them with your finger up and down. Add a link to the video clarity. [a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7s0sgEvzvEQ&feature=youtu.be)! Please know how to do it?

Comment: Use some kind of gesture detector, figure out the coordinates of the finger, and try to calculate if they're in the textView area. That's just a basic idea. Google more into gesture detectors and their methods.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
       text1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                text1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#dedede"));
                text2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
                text3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
                text4.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
                text5.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
                return true;
            }
        });


text2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                text1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
                text2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#dedede"));
                text3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
                text4.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
                text5.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
                return true;
            }
        });

text3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                text1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
                text2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
                text3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#dedede"));
                text4.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
                text5.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
                return true;
            }
        });


text4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                text1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
                text2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
                text3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
                text4.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#dedede"));
                text5.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
                return true;
            }
        });


text5.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                text1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
                text2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
                text3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
                text4.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
                text5.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#dedede"));
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: This only works when I click and change everything else. I need to do it exactly like it is in that video.

Comment: @RomanBranislav In video also when you touch textview it changes color. If you want to do that automatically then use thread(runOnUithread) with loop.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `View.OnTouchListener` in your `Activity` / `Fragment`. And then, in your `onTouch` method, check which TextView is currently getting touched. Set highlight color for it and remove highlight color for others.

Pseudo-code -

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  // Loop through TextViews
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if(v.equals(textViews[i])) {
          textViews[i].setTextColor(R.color.my_highlight_color);
      } else {
          textViews[i].setTextColor(R.color.my_color);
      }
  }

    return true;
}
```